# 2010 Toyota FJ cruiser Transmission shudder

Tags: toyota, transmission, fjcruiser

I have a 2010 Toyota FJ cruiser. Has about 250k miles. I noticed a shudder at about 35-40 miles an hour as well as at 55-60 mph. Took it to Toyota dealership and was told it was the transmission and I should replace it. Because of supply chain problems they could not find a replacement through their channels (Quality Used Transmissions).

I found a used one with 55k miles on it and purchased it. Just had it installed and the problem persists. The Toyota  dealership mechanic says it is the transmission! Must be bad. I find it very suspicious that 2 transmissions could have the same problem.

Anyone have a suggestion?
BTW current transmission has a 1 year parts and labor warranty.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you put in a new torque converter? This sounds like it could be a TC lock-up issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is going to be a difficult one to diagnose remotely.

Before doing anything else with the expensive gearbox/transmission, I would check some other components to make sure they are not causing the issue.

- The prop shaft
- Transmission mounts
- Engine mounts

A worn or unbalanced prop shaft can definitely cause shuddering as it spins at a resonant frequency.  I would check that first.  A quick search shows that the car has one piece prop shaft, but if I am wrong and it has a two piece, then also check the bearing in the centre mount.   Check the universal joints too.

Check the transmission and engine mounts, because if these allow the power train to move this can cause shuddering too.